# How to get the base url in config.xml file

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento2.3.5, base-url

How to get the base url into magento2 module app/etc/config.xml file.

```
<storefront>
    <report_uri>https://www.example.com/</report_uri>
</storefront>
```

instead of https://www.example.com/ I need to get the base url

Please anyone help me.

thanks

Comment: Try {{baseUrl}}

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: {{config path='web/unsecure/base_url'}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the base url in magento `{{config path='web/unsecure/base_url'}}`

Comment: Let me know if it works

Comment: Yes. it's working